# Having trouble trying to access nested data

Tags: javascript, nested

So I have a data structure like below and I'm trying to access inside tournaments the '_id' Any help would be great. What would I need to console.log to get 29?

```js
const sports = {
  "queryUrl": "config_tournaments/1/17",
  "doc": [{
    "event": "config_tournaments",
    "_dob": 1647341355,
    "_maxage": 600,
    "_configid": 12457,
    "data": {
      "tournaments": [{
        "_doc": "tournament",
        "_id": 29,
        "_sid": 1,
        "_rcid": 17,
        "_isk": 1,
        "_tid": 29,
        "_utid": 45,
        "name": "Bundesliga",
        "abbr": "BUN",
        "ground": null,
        "friendly": false,
        "seasonid": 84476,
        "currentseason": 84476,
        "year": "21/22",
        "seasontype": "21",
        "seasontypename": "Regular Season",
        "seasontypeunique": "68",
        "livetable": 57152,
        "cuprosterid": null,
        "roundbyround": true,
        "tournamentlevelorder": 1,
        "tournamentlevelname": "1st level",
        "outdated": false,
        "_sk": false
      }]
    }
  }]
}

console.log(sports.doc[0].data)
```

Comment: `console.log(sports.doc[0].data.tournaments[0]._id);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
console.log(sports.doc[0].data.tournaments[0]._id)
```

Comment: `tournaments` is an array

Comment: @Madilus please mark this as the answer if it is the solution you expected